# Sorting 2d arraylist based on two elements

Tags: java

I am trying to sort a 2d Arraylist based on the 1st element and when comparing if the two elements are the same then sort it by the 2nd element.

So my Arraylist  looks like

```
 [[1, 4, 0], [2, 5, 2], [3, 5, 3], [4, 3, 6]]
```

and I want it too look like this

```
 [[4, 3, 6], [1, 4, 0], [2, 5, 2], [3, 5, 3]]
```

This is my ArrayList

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> processes = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is what I have so far using selection sort

```
int smallInt;
int j;
int smallIntIndex;
for(int i = 1; i<=processes.size();i++){
    smallInt = processes.get(i-1).get(1);
    smallIntIndex = i-1;
    for(j=i;j<processes.size();j++){
        if(processes.get(j).get(1)==smallInt){
          //not exactly sure what goes in here
        }else if(processes.get(j).get(1)<smallInt){
            smallInt = processes.get(j).get(1);
            smallIntIndex = j;
        }
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = processes.get(smallIntIndex);
    processes.set(smallIntIndex,processes.get(i-1));
    processes.set(i-1,temp);
}
```

Comment: How is `[[4, 3, 6], [1, 4, 0], [2, 5, 2], [3, 5, 3]]` sorted?

Comment: It is sorted based on the 1st element(1st index of the nested array list).

Comment: How about using buiilt-in sort functions like `processes.sort((firstElement, secondElement) -> Integer.compare(firstElement.get(1), secondElement.get(1));`

Comment: No, it's sorted on the second element (with index 1) in the array. If we are to use the correct terms. If the values are equal then you need to check vs the next value in the inner list (yeah, arraylist are actually lists. So it not common to use them in this way.)

Comment: That worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are the labels (e.g. 1 or 2 or 3 - first / second / third entry) from a restricted set (e.g. only digits)?
If so (as I think it is), you can sort them by applying [Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).